# MySQL fetch users who are not yet friends

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello guys I'm new to this, I need your help to fetch users who are not yet friends.

This is my tables:

```
  Users 
  id    username   
  1     kyle
  2     jane
  3     jim
  4     carla

  Friends
  id    username  friend
  1     kyle      jane
  2     jane      kyle
  3     kyle      jim
  4     jim       kyle
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
  SELECT username
  FROM users AS u
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM friends AS f
              WHERE (f.username = 'kyle')
             )
```

But I get no results retrieved. It should display 1 record and that is carla. Any ideas? I would gladly appreciate your help. Thanks. Also, can you suggest much more robust approach to this?

Comment: Create your data structure and inserts in here, and people can try to solve your problem easier. http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Btw, you should use usersID on the friends table, not the actual username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long hours of finding solution, this is what I've got:

```
 SELECT * FROM users AS u 
 WHERE u.username NOT IN 
 (
     SELECT f.username FROM friends as f
     WHERE f.username = 'kyle'
     OR f.friend = 'kyle'
 )
```

I hope this will help others as well.

Comment: Friends should be a two column table where each column is the ID of a user.  Each friend record represents a "friendship."  That way you're not duplicating data across two tables. What if one of the users changes his/her name?  Your current schema is fragile.

Comment: Yes thanks for enlightening me, I have updated my schema and this is my test data.

Answer (score 2):

```
select a.username 
  from users a 
   left join friends b 
      on a.username= b.username 
        where b.username is null;
```

Also, a simple better approach would be:

```
user table

userid  username
1       kyle
2       jane
3       jim
4       carla

friends table

friendid  userid  friend
1          1       jane
2          2       kyle
3          1       jim
4          3       kyle
```

Comment: thanks! but what if I want to just filter by username = 'kyle' ?

Comment: just change (b.username is null) to (b.username = 'kyle') in your query

Comment: But I'm getting kyle's friends when I did that.

Comment: Then, change the filter with (friends='kyle').