# MySQL fetch users who are not yet friends (excluded self)

Tags: php, mysql

This is the continuation of my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28292163/mysql-fetch-users-who-are-not-yet-friends?noredirect=1#comment44937551_28292163)

So basically, I want to fetch users who are not my friends. However, if a user has just signed up and he has no friends yet, he should be able to see all users not his friends.

Please check my sql fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b158fb/4)

```
 Users 
 id    username   
 1     kyle
 2     jane
 3     jim
 4     carla

 Friends
 id    username  friend
 1     kyle      jane
 2     jane      kyle
 3     kyle      jim
 4     jim       kyle
```

When I query Kyle's not his friends:

```
SELECT * FROM users AS u 
                    WHERE u.username NOT IN 
                    (
                        SELECT f.username FROM friends as f
                        WHERE f.username = 'kyle'
                        OR f.friend = 'kyle'
                    )
```

It's displaying all users not his friends. However, when I query Carla's, she is included in the result set. She doesn't have friends yet but she shows up in the result set. I want to remove (self) from the results and just display users not yet her friends.

Any ideas? I would gladly appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Friends` table should relate `IDs` and not `Names`.

That said, here's the query that will return a list of all *non-friends* for **every** user:

```
SELECT u1.username as `User`, GROUP_CONCAT(u2.username) as `Not friends with`
FROM Users u1
JOIN Users u2 ON u1.id <> u2.id 
LEFT JOIN Friends f ON u1.id = f.user AND u2.id = f.friend   
WHERE f.friend IS NULL
GROUP BY u1.id
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4178451/10)

The same for a single user ('jim'):

```
SELECT u1.username as `User`, GROUP_CONCAT(u2.username) as `Not friends with`
FROM Users u1
JOIN Users u2 ON u1.id <> u2.id 
LEFT JOIN Friends f ON u1.id = f.user AND u2.id = f.friend   
WHERE f.friend IS NULL
      AND u1.username = 'jim'
```

And [**Single-User Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4178451/12)

Comment: thanks a lot dude! Thank you also for explaining this. I'll change my db structure.